# How to use time to determine if a function should run?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

I want to run a google script on weekdays at 8, 11, 1, and 3. I am using a time-based trigger to run a function, checkTime(), hourly that checks the time and runs if it that day and time.

The time trigger in Google Scripts is limited and I'd like to use this so I don't have to create (5 days x 4 different times = 20 triggers). Having it run against a function seems like a more simple solution, but I just can't figure it out. This is the pseduo-code that I've come up with. Can anyone point me in the right direction or show an example?

```
  var d = new Date();

  if(dayOfWeek == 'Monday' || ... || dayOfWeek == 'Friday') &&
    d == '8:00' || d == '11:00' || d == '13:00' || d == '15:00'){
    myFunction();
  }

}
```

The expected result is on M, T, W, R, or F at 8, 11, 13, & 15 the conditional should evaluate to True and the function run. All other times should evaluate to False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script doesn't support `Set` or `includes` method so you may to have to use old JavaScript to get this to work.

```
var d = new Date();  
if (d.getDay() < 6 && [8, 11, 13, 15].indexOf(d.getHours()) !== -1) {
  myFunction();
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this was really helpful. I tried the other answers but was running into issues until I looked up what App Script supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date(); // Date time now

const isWeekday = d.getDay() < 6; // Saturday
const isCorrectTime = [8, 11, 13, 15].includes(d.getHours()); // For correct hours
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `getUTCDay` and the `getUTCHours()` methods of `Date` objects.

The test would look as follow :

```
const now = new Date();
const [day,  hour] = [now.getUTCDay(), now.getUTCHours()];
const okDays = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const okHours = new Set([8, 11, 13, 15]);

if (okHours.has(hour) && okDays.has(day)) {
    // do stuff
}
```